# child_process spawn doesnt work if i run in the parent folder

Tags: node.js, child-process

So I am working with child_process spawn for sending and receiving data from nodejs and python.

here is my code

```
var py = spawn('python3', ['./python.py']),
var responseArray = []
py.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(sendData));
    py.stdin.end();
    py.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        responseArray = JSON.parse(data.toString())
    });
    py.stdout.on('end', function () {
        console.log(responseArray)
    });
```

So in the code, I showed if I run directly like this *node project.js*, I receive the data the python sends to nodeJs, but if I run from the parent folder like this *node folder/project.js*, it will go immediately to stdout, showing the data empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`child_process.spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options) uses by default the same current working directory (cwd) of the Node process:

> Use `cwd` to specify the working directory from which the process is spawned. If not given, the default is to inherit the current working directory.

So if you invoke the JS script from a parent folder, your CWD is that parent folder, but your `python.py` file is not there.

As described in the linked docs, you can use a 3rd argument to `spawn` to specify options, in particular `cwd` that should be used:

```js
spawn('python3', ['./python.py'], {
  cwd: './folder' // Or better: an absolute path
})
```

...or simply fix the path to your Python script:

```js
spawn('python3', ['./folder/python.py'])
```